# ImportError: No module named multiarray

Tags: pickle

When I run this code:

```
from numpy.core import multiarray
import cPickle as pickle

exp_number = 13

model.summary()
losses = pickle.load(open('/home/ubuntu/nilmtk/nilmtk/neuralnilm/tmpdata/history_exp' + str(exp_number) + '.pickle' , 'rb'))
test_set = pickle.load(open('/home/ubuntu/nilmtk/nilmtk/neuralnilm/tmpdata/TestSet.pickle', 'rb'))

X_test = test_set['X_test']
Y_test = test_set["Y_test"]
```

I get this issue:

> ImportError Traceback (most recent call last) in () 5 exp_number = 15
>   6 with
>   open('/home/ubuntu/nilmtk/nilmtk/neuralnilm/tmpdata/history_exp' +
>   str(exp_number) + '.pickle' , 'rb') as f: ----> 7 losses =
>   pickle.load(f) 8 # load the test set 9 with
>   open('/home/ubuntu/nilmtk/nilmtk/neuralnilm/tmpdata/TestSet.pickle',
>   'rb') as v:
>
> ImportError: No module named multiarray

Can someone please help me?